# Check services used by a specific program in linux

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am writing a C program to print numbers from 1 to 1 million. Now is their any way through which I can check the services provided by linux operating system to that C program?

Comment: I am not sure but are you looking for this:- # lsof -Pnl +M -i4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run your program under `strace` to see what system calls (calls to the OS kernel) your program does.

Note that there are going to be quite a few system calls made by the run-time linker and C library before `main` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see Linux at work try ps to scope the individual PID. df will tell you saved information on the disk.

ps aux --sort=-pcpu,+pmem

I think that is the very command you need.